# How can I increase EVM time in web3.py?

Tags: web3js, evm, web3.py, web3-providers, timestamp

When working with web3.js, Truffle and Ganache, I can do this:

```
web3.currentProvider.send({method: "evm_increaseTime", params: [numOfSeconds]});
```

How can I do the equivalent in web3.py?

When I do:

```
from web3 import HTTPProvider
for func in dir(HTTPProvider):
    if not func.startswith('_'):
        print(func)
```

I get:

```
decode_rpc_response
encode_rpc_request
endpoint_uri
get_request_headers
get_request_kwargs
isConnected
logger
make_request
middlewares
request_func
```

Is it possibly one of these functions that I need to call?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

I've found that I can encode the request like so:

```
provider = Web3(HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545")).providers[0]
request = encode_rpc_request("evm_increaseTime", [123])
```

When printing `request`, I get:

```
b'{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "evm_increaseTime", "params": [123], "id": 0}'
```

But how do I send this request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this seems to to the job:

```
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"))
provider = web3.providers[0]
provider.make_request("evm_increaseTime", [numOfSeconds])
```